# Jade /Pug - Bootstrap columns not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, pug

I am creating a simple form with jade / pug and Bootstrap. But label and field are being displayed vertically instead of each one in a column.

Am I missing something?

```
div.container-fluid(style='margin-top:40px')
    div.form-group.row
        label.col-2.col-form-label(for='username') Username
        div.col-10
            input.form-control(type='text' value=user.username id="username" disabled="true")
    .form-group.row
        label.col-2.col-form-label(for='first_name') Nombre
        .col-10
            input.form-control(type='text' value=user.first_name id="first_name" disabled="true")
    .form-group.row
        label.col-2.col-form-label(for='first_name') Apellidos
        .col-10
            input.form-control(type='text' value=user.last_name id="last_name" disabled="true")
    .form-group.row
        label.col-2.col-form-label(for='email') Email
        .col-10
            input.form-control(type='text' value=user.email id="email" disabled="true")
```

Comment: Please create a fiddle of your code. Your current code is [not working](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Vzjqwz).

Comment: @htafoya, try adding <form> element after container

Comment: @ChandraShekhar noup :(

Comment: Indentation issue.

Comment: it is working fine.. check this link ................ https://codepen.io/chandrashekhar/pen/ayZXLj

Comment: uhmm thank you, probably it has to do with a super container that is affecting the form. I'll check it out.